# Using CSS in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change CSS elements depending on situations used in javascript.

an example I had tried was:

```
if ('image'=="clicked")
{blahblahblah}
```

'image' would be my div id or div tag in CSS.
I know in Jquery I can use `$('#image').click`, but I don't think it Jquery will be good for my situation.

Comment: And why would jQuery not be good for you? And why did you add it as a tag then?

Comment: Removed Jquery tag, If you don't want jQuery.

Comment: I don't understand this question? You need to clarify what you want. As it's written this isn't clear

Comment: `if ('image'=="clicked")` will be false always and forever

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Anyone who thinks he doesn't mean `when a specific image is clicked` please stop reading.  It's obvious he means that, but has just expressed it badly.  The jQuery he provided shows *exactly* that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector). It's powerful, accepting any valid CSS selector. You can even start from another element, such as `myElement.querySelector`, to only get children of that element that match the selector. Very useful!

Just be aware that IE7 and below do not support this function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `id` as `image`

```
document.getElementById('image').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
}​;​
```

Comment: @Archer, sorry, I have updated